# GroupBy and Sum in prisma

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I have the following Prisma schema for MongoDB database

```
model orders {
  id             String              @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  totalAmount    Int
  createdAt      DateTime            @db.Date
}
```

Now I want to apply groupby based on dates and give the sum on the basis of month like

```
{
  "january": 4567,
   "February": 7785
}
```

I tried the following as mentioned in documentation but its not working

```
const sales = await prisma.orders.groupBy({
    by: ["createdAt"],
    _sum: {
      totalAmount: true,
    },
    orderBy: { createdAt: "desc" },
  });
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is not any solution in Prisma right now. So To achieve the desired result, I use Prisma to fetch the relevant data from MongoDB and then perform the grouping and summing on the retrieved data in JavaScript as follow.

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function sumTotalAmountByMonth() {
  const orders = await prisma.orders.findMany();

  const salesByMonth = orders.reduce((result, { createdAt, totalAmount }) => {
    const month = createdAt.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    result[month] = (result[month] || 0) + totalAmount;
    return result;
  }, {});

  return salesByMonth;
}

sumTotalAmountByMonth()
  .then((salesByMonth) => console.log(salesByMonth))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => prisma.$disconnect());
```